# Dynamic tables and DOM

Tags: javascript

I've created a table through HTML where one of the columns contains a series of buttons to add a new row, delete that specific row or move the row up or down. I'm able to add a new row but I'm having some trouble removing the same row the button was pressed on. I used an alert method to display the row index and when I click the button, it shows the row index is undefined but if I click anywhere else in that same row, it shows the correct row index!

I'm fairly new at Javascript and would like to do this using pure JavaScript.

I set an alert to figure out which row index is being called and for some reason, when I click the button, it says the row index is undefined but the next alert box shows the correct row index.

```
    function removeData(x) {
        var ind = x.rowIndex;
        alert(ind);
        //document.getElementById("table1").deleteRow(ind);
    }

   <table id="table1" border="2px">
            <tr>
                <th>Column 1</th> <th>Column 2</th> <th>Column 3</th> <th>Column 4</th> 
            </tr>   
            <tr id="enterData" onclick="removeData(this)">
                <td id="buttons"><input type="button" value="Remove" id="button1" onclick="removeData(this)" /> 
                    <input type="button" value="Up" id="button2" onclick="up()" />
                    <input type="button" value="Down" id="button3" onclick="down()" /> 
                    <input type="button" value="Add" id="button4" onclick="editTable()" />
                </td>
            </tr>       
        </table>
```

Comment: Why do you have onclick="removeData(this)" on both your `<tr>` element and your `<input>` elements?

Comment: @Jeff-Meadows I was having trouble using the button to remove a row, so I included it in the table row hoping that the button is encapsulated in there so it would pass through the correct row index.

Comment: `rowIndex` is a property of table rows, not input elements within the row. You need `x.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex` to get the row index (the button's parent is the `<td>`, its parent is the `<tr>`.

Answer (score 1):

You're seeing two alerts because the click event is bubbling up through the DOM.

Both your `tr` and an `input` element have `onclick=removeData(this)` handlers.

First the click event fires on the button (which is why `rowIndex` is undefined), and then it bubbles up to the `tr` (which is why the second alert shows you the correct value).

Comment: Thank you! That resolves part of the problem I was experiencing. I took out the onclick=removeData(this) from the tr and removed the comments from the last line of the function. The row above the row with the button gets deleted, however, I want the row that the button is on to be deleted.

Comment: If you removed the `tr` onclick handler, then the `this` that gets passed to the `removeData` is an `HTMLInputElement`, which doesn't have a `rowIndex`. Which means you're calling `table.deleteRow` with `undefined` and not an index. It would appear that when you do that, it just deleted the first row. You're going to need to find a way to grab the row instance.

Comment: @Barmar: Thank you, I see where I went wrong! I tried using     x.trButtons.tdButtons.rowIndex , where tdButtons is the     <td> and trButtons is the     <tr> but in Google Chrome's javascript console it gave an uncaught type error: Cannot read property 'tdButtons' of undefined.